# Вставить значение из другой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, создать правильный запрос.

Есть две таблицы: orders, zakaz_tovar.

```
Orders: id, date, name.
Zakaz_tovar: id, date, name.
```

Обе эти таблицы, имеют одинаковые значения ID.

Как мне получить значение orders(name) по ID и записать его в zakaz_tovar(name)?

Comment: что значит записать? вставить новое или обновить?

Answer (score 1):

Если судить по именам полей - поле namе текстовое и поэтому это уже не правильно. для связи между таблицами правильнее использовать чиловые поля. А то что у Вас - это дублирование таблиц, даже если эти таблицы отличаются другими полями.
`UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY zakaz_tovar
    SET zakaz_tovar.name = (SELECT
    orders.name
    FROM orders
     WHERE orders.id = 1)
     WHERE zakaz_tovar.id = 1;`
вариант предложен для обновления поля